# PhpMyAdmin does not show Query results operations at the bottom of Query Result

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I can see Query results operations which gives me a way to export my query result for some queries but not for others where there is a query with bunch of joins. I feel its the type of Query. Is that the reason or is it the number of results?

Snapshot of the actual query : Replaced the variables for security reason

```
SELECT u.d, u.u, d1.d, u.f, u.e, u.m, u.b, u.s, u.g, u.ge, q1.c as Q1,
q2.c as Q2,
q31.c IS NOT NULL as Q31,
q32.c IS NOT NULL as Q32,
q33.c IS NOT NULL as Q33,
q34.c IS NOT NULL as Q34,
q35.c IS NOT NULL as Q35,
q36.c IS NOT NULL as Q36,
q37.c IS NOT NULL as Q37,
q38.c IS NOT NULL as Q38,
q39.c IS NOT NULL as Q39,
q310.c IS NOT NULL as Q310,
q311.c IS NOT NULL as Q311,
q312.c IS NOT NULL as Q312,
q313.c IS NOT NULL as Q313,
q41.c IS NOT NULL as Q41,
q42.c IS NOT NULL as Q42,
q43.c IS NOT NULL as Q43,
q44.c IS NOT NULL as Q44,
q45.c IS NOT NULL as Q45,
q46.c IS NOT NULL as Q46,
q47.c IS NOT NULL as Q47,
q48.c IS NOT NULL as Q48,
q5.c as Q5,
q61.c IS NOT NULL as Q61,
q62.c IS NOT NULL as Q62,
q63.c IS NOT NULL as Q63,
q64.c IS NOT NULL as Q64,
q65.c IS NOT NULL as Q65,
q7.c as Q7,
q81.c IS NOT NULL as Q81,
q82.c IS NOT NULL as Q82,
q83.c IS NOT NULL as Q83,
q84.c IS NOT NULL as Q84,
q85.c IS NOT NULL as Q85,
q9.openresponse as Q9
INTO
FROM `user` u 
LEFT JOIN dsschools d1 ON d1.name = u.s
INNER JOIN r q1 ON q1.u=u.u AND q1.qid=1

INNER JOIN r q2 ON q2.u=u.u AND q2.qid=2

LEFT JOIN r q31 ON q31.u=u.u AND q31.qid=3 AND q31.c=1
LEFT JOIN r q32 ON q32.u=u.u AND q32.qid=3 AND q32.c=2
LEFT JOIN r q33 ON q33.u=u.u AND q33.qid=3 AND q33.c=3
LEFT JOIN r q34 ON q34.u=u.u AND q34.qid=3 AND q34.c=4
LEFT JOIN r q35 ON q35.u=u.u AND q35.qid=3 AND q35.c=5
LEFT JOIN r q36 ON q36.u=u.u AND q36.qid=3 AND q36.c=6
LEFT JOIN r q37 ON q37.u=u.u AND q37.qid=3 AND q37.c=7
LEFT JOIN r q38 ON q38.u=u.u AND q38.qid=3 AND q38.c=8
LEFT JOIN r q39 ON q39.u=u.u AND q39.qid=3 AND q39.c=9
LEFT JOIN r q310 ON q310.u=u.u AND q310.qid=3 AND q310.c=10
LEFT JOIN r q311 ON q311.u=u.u AND q311.qid=3 AND q311.c=11
LEFT JOIN r q312 ON q312.u=u.u AND q312.qid=3 AND q312.c=12
LEFT JOIN r q313 ON q313.u=u.u AND q313.qid=3 AND q313.c=13

LEFT JOIN r q41 ON q41.u=u.u AND q41.qid=4 AND q41.c=1
LEFT JOIN r q42 ON q42.u=u.u AND q42.qid=4 AND q42.c=2
LEFT JOIN r q43 ON q43.u=u.u AND q43.qid=4 AND q43.c=3
LEFT JOIN r q44 ON q44.u=u.u AND q44.qid=4 AND q44.c=4
LEFT JOIN r q45 ON q45.u=u.u AND q45.qid=4 AND q45.c=5
LEFT JOIN r q46 ON q46.u=u.u AND q46.qid=4 AND q46.c=6
LEFT JOIN r q47 ON q47.u=u.u AND q47.qid=4 AND q47.c=7
LEFT JOIN r q48 ON q48.u=u.u AND q48.qid=4 AND q48.c=8

INNER JOIN r q5 ON q5.u=u.u AND q5.qid=5

LEFT JOIN r q61 ON q61.u=u.u AND q61.qid=6 AND q61.c=1
LEFT JOIN r q62 ON q62.u=u.u AND q62.qid=6 AND q62.c=2
LEFT JOIN r q63 ON q63.u=u.u AND q63.qid=6 AND q63.c=3
LEFT JOIN r q64 ON q64.u=u.u AND q64.qid=6 AND q64.c=4
LEFT JOIN r q65 ON q65.u=u.u AND q65.qid=6 AND q65.c=5

INNER JOIN r q7 ON q7.u=u.u AND q7.qid=7

LEFT JOIN r q81 ON q81.u=u.u AND q81.qid=8 AND q81.c=1
LEFT JOIN r q82 ON q82.u=u.u AND q82.qid=8 AND q82.c=2
LEFT JOIN r q83 ON q83.u=u.u AND q83.qid=8 AND q83.c=3
LEFT JOIN r q84 ON q84.u=u.u AND q84.qid=8 AND q84.c=4
LEFT JOIN r q85 ON q85.u=u.u AND q85.qid=8 AND q85.c=5

INNER JOIN r q9 ON q9.u=u.u AND q9.qid=9
LIMIT 20000,10000
```

Comment: Why so many `LEFT JOIN`? Maybe it is time to optimize your database layout or your queries.

Comment: if you don't received any error, probably it's your query that will take A LOT in return the result, you have too much joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons may be that so many fields were returned which disabled that export option at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

It is because, your query is quite long, and phpMyAdmin version 4.0.3 still in time of writing and my use, has this probably "bug" that when you send long query, including any commentary. It wont display export options - Query result operations.

Example:  add any quite long comment (or command) it will stop to work, remove it, options will be there displayed again